# Onesignal on Xamarin Android is not working

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, onesignal

I have a Xamarin forms application and I am using OneSignal to push notifications.

On iOS it's working fine, but on Android it does not.

I have this call `OneSignal.Current.StartInit("api_key").EndInit();` in a dependency that I am resolving on the first page.
I remove Xamarin.GooglePlayService.Gcm library because it was throwing me an error about having GCM and not FCM and some obsolete/deprecated thing.
Do any of you have any idea on where to start? I googled some of the phrases here but did not found any leads.

After executing that line I get this error:

```
[chi.calendarap] Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.onesignal.LocationGMS$LocationUpdateListener>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener;
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.LocationGMS.getLocation(android.content.Context, boolean, com.onesignal.LocationGMS$LocationHandler) (LocationGMS.java:125)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.OneSignal.startLocationUpdate() (OneSignal.java:928)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.OneSignal.startRegistrationOrOnSession() (OneSignal.java:905)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.OneSignal.doSessionInit() (OneSignal.java:820)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.OneSignal.init(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, com.onesignal.OneSignal$NotificationOpenedHandler, com.onesignal.OneSignal$NotificationReceivedHandler) (OneSignal.java:710)
[chi.calendarap]   at void mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run() (RunnableImplementor.java:-2)
[chi.calendarap]   at void mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run() (RunnableImplementor.java:30)
[chi.calendarap]   at void android.os.Handler.handleCallback(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:907)
[chi.calendarap]   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
[chi.calendarap]   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:216)
[chi.calendarap]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:7625)
[chi.calendarap]   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:524)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:987)
[chi.calendarap] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ro.stilvechi.calendarapp-ymrN-LSl8z75O8CBvOkGRg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ro.stilvechi.calendarapp-ymrN-LSl8z75O8CBvOkGRg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/ro.stilvechi.calendarapp-ymrN-LSl8z75O8CBvOkGRg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]
[chi.calendarap]   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
[chi.calendarap]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
[chi.calendarap]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.LocationGMS.getLocation(android.content.Context, boolean, com.onesignal.LocationGMS$LocationHandler) (LocationGMS.java:125)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.OneSignal.startLocationUpdate() (OneSignal.java:928)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.OneSignal.startRegistrationOrOnSession() (OneSignal.java:905)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.OneSignal.doSessionInit() (OneSignal.java:820)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.OneSignal.init(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, com.onesignal.OneSignal$NotificationOpenedHandler, com.onesignal.OneSignal$NotificationReceivedHandler) (OneSignal.java:710)
[chi.calendarap]   at void mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run() (RunnableImplementor.java:-2)
[chi.calendarap]   at void mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run() (RunnableImplementor.java:30)
[chi.calendarap]   at void android.os.Handler.handleCallback(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:907)
[chi.calendarap]   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
[chi.calendarap]   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:216)
[chi.calendarap]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:7625)
[chi.calendarap]   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:524)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:987)
[chi.calendarap] 
[chi.calendarap] Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.onesignal.LocationGMS$LocationUpdateListener>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener;
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.LocationGMS.getLocation(android.content.Context, boolean, com.onesignal.LocationGMS$LocationHandler) (LocationGMS.java:125)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.OneSignal.startLocationUpdate() (OneSignal.java:928)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.OneSignal.startRegistrationOrOnSession() (OneSignal.java:905)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.OneSignal.doSessionInit() (OneSignal.java:820)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.OneSignal.init(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, com.onesignal.OneSignal$NotificationOpenedHandler, com.onesignal.OneSignal$NotificationReceivedHandler) (OneSignal.java:710)
[chi.calendarap]   at void mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run() (RunnableImplementor.java:-2)
[chi.calendarap]   at void mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run() (RunnableImplementor.java:30)
[chi.calendarap]   at void android.os.Handler.handleCallback(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:907)
[chi.calendarap]   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
[chi.calendarap]   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:216)
[chi.calendarap]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:7625)
[chi.calendarap]   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:524)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:987)
[chi.calendarap] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ro.stilvechi.calendarapp-ymrN-LSl8z75O8CBvOkGRg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ro.stilvechi.calendarapp-ymrN-LSl8z75O8CBvOkGRg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/ro.stilvechi.calendarapp-ymrN-LSl8z75O8CBvOkGRg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]
[chi.calendarap]   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
[chi.calendarap]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
[chi.calendarap]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.LocationGMS.getLocation(android.content.Context, boolean, com.onesignal.LocationGMS$LocationHandler) (LocationGMS.java:125)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.OneSignal.startLocationUpdate() (OneSignal.java:928)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.OneSignal.startRegistrationOrOnSession() (OneSignal.java:905)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.OneSignal.doSessionInit() (OneSignal.java:820)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.OneSignal.init(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, com.onesignal.OneSignal$NotificationOpenedHandler, com.onesignal.OneSignal$NotificationReceivedHandler) (OneSignal.java:710)
[chi.calendarap]   at void mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run() (RunnableImplementor.java:-2)
[chi.calendarap]   at void mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run() (RunnableImplementor.java:30)
[chi.calendarap]   at void android.os.Handler.handleCallback(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:907)
[chi.calendarap]   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
[chi.calendarap]   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:216)
[chi.calendarap]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:7625)
[chi.calendarap]   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:524)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:987)
[chi.calendarap] 
[chi.calendarap] Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.onesignal.LocationGMS$LocationUpdateListener>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener;
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.LocationGMS.getLocation(android.content.Context, boolean, com.onesignal.LocationGMS$LocationHandler) (LocationGMS.java:125)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.OneSignal.startLocationUpdate() (OneSignal.java:928)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.OneSignal.startRegistrationOrOnSession() (OneSignal.java:905)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.OneSignal.doSessionInit() (OneSignal.java:820)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.OneSignal.init(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, com.onesignal.OneSignal$NotificationOpenedHandler, com.onesignal.OneSignal$NotificationReceivedHandler) (OneSignal.java:710)
[chi.calendarap]   at void mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run() (RunnableImplementor.java:-2)
[chi.calendarap]   at void mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run() (RunnableImplementor.java:30)
[chi.calendarap]   at void android.os.Handler.handleCallback(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:907)
[chi.calendarap]   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
[chi.calendarap]   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:216)
[chi.calendarap]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:7625)
[chi.calendarap]   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:524)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:987)
[chi.calendarap] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ro.stilvechi.calendarapp-ymrN-LSl8z75O8CBvOkGRg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ro.stilvechi.calendarapp-ymrN-LSl8z75O8CBvOkGRg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/ro.stilvechi.calendarapp-ymrN-LSl8z75O8CBvOkGRg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]
[chi.calendarap]   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
[chi.calendarap]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
[chi.calendarap]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.LocationGMS.getLocation(android.content.Context, boolean, com.onesignal.LocationGMS$LocationHandler) (LocationGMS.java:125)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.OneSignal.startLocationUpdate() (OneSignal.java:928)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.OneSignal.startRegistrationOrOnSession() (OneSignal.java:905)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.OneSignal.doSessionInit() (OneSignal.java:820)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.onesignal.OneSignal.init(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, com.onesignal.OneSignal$NotificationOpenedHandler, com.onesignal.OneSignal$NotificationReceivedHandler) (OneSignal.java:710)
[chi.calendarap]   at void mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run() (RunnableImplementor.java:-2)
[chi.calendarap]   at void mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run() (RunnableImplementor.java:30)
[chi.calendarap]   at void android.os.Handler.handleCallback(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:907)
[chi.calendarap]   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
[chi.calendarap]   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:216)
[chi.calendarap]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:7625)
[chi.calendarap]   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:524)
[chi.calendarap]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:987)
[chi.calendarap] 
[NetworkSecurityConfig] No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
[FirebaseApp] com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Proguard.cfg](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/proguard?tabs=macos#overview)

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
```

Comment: I don't have a Proguard configuration. Nor is my project set to use any shrinker.

Comment: you don't have even r8?

Comment: Nothing is selected in that box.